# Mi input se deforma en mozilla firefox

Tags: css

Mi *input type search* se desforma en el navegador de **mozilla firefox** mientras que en **Google Chrome** y los demás navegadores se muestra sin problemas y desconozco la causa del porque sucede esto.

Estoy trabajando con el Framework de estilos **MaterializeCSS** y decidí personalizar un poco el *input type search* debido a que no me gusta el diseño que este trae por defecto y escribí solo un poquito de estilos CSS para darle un mejor aspecto.

### Este es el estilo con el que personalice al search

```
/* Input de buscador */
.input-field input[type=search] {
  padding: 10px 10px !important;
  margin: 12px 3.3rem !important;
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

### Este es el aspecto que tiene el sitio web en Firefox

[image: Aspecto del buscador en Firefox]

Espero me puedan ayudar, un saludo

Comment: ¿Porqué le das un padding absoluto? Te sugiero probar con la unidad `rem`.

Comment: Y con eso se solucionaría mi error?

Comment: Tienes que ir probando diferentes medidas de padding y diferentes resoluciones, de esta forma tu input será responsivo. Tal como está ahora, y sin ver el resto de reglas CSS es difícil determinar si eso soluciona el problema. A simple vista, estás metiendo un padding de 10px en top y 10px en bottom. Si la resolución de tu pantalla tiene 1280px de alto, quitando el espacio de la barra superior e inferior, digamos que tienes 1000px de viewport, estás asignando 1% de espacio entre el borde superior de tu input y el texto y 1% de espacio en la parte inferior.

Comment: normalizaste lo valores predeterminados de tu pagina primero antes de aplicarle el ccs?
intenta normalizar los valores primero con https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Si reduces el tamaño de la ventana del navegador, digamos que te quedan 800px de altura en el viewport, entonces estás asignando ahora 1.25% de espaciado. Es por ello que una medida absoluta no es amiga del diseño responsivo, excepto en casos muy específicos, y el tuyo no es uno de estos. Por lo tanto, debes jugar con las Media Queries y usar medidas relativas, como `rem`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad la solución a este problema es sencillo pero no todos conocen.
Existe un comando en **CSS** que es para especificar que una regla es única y exclusivamente para un navegador y en este caso al tu no estas usando **normalice** puedes aplicar esta regla y dentro de ella escribir la misma reglas que usaste para que se vea así en todos los navegadores pero puedes editar las propiedades para que esta se ajuste única y exclusivamente a **Firefox**

### El código de que te hablo es:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   /* Input de buscador */
   .input-field input[type=search] {
      padding: 10px 10px !important;
      margin: 12px 3.3rem !important;
      border: 1px solid black !important;
   }
}
```

Colócalo de esta forma en tu hoja de estilos **CSS** y solo ponte a jugar con las propiedades hasta que tu *input search* encaje perfectamente en el header de tu sitio o hasta lograr verse como a ti te gustaría y lo puedes hacer sin temor ya que estos cambios serán única y exclusivamente para **mozilla firefox** y en otros navegadores se seguirá mostrando como antes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente agregar `max-height` al css donde tienes el elemento y le estableces el valor que se ajuste a los navegadores que usas.